# Intellij IDEA: Reopen files (Tabs) on start

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, ide

When I close IDEA and start it again, all open Files (Tabs) are closed and the project tree is collapsed. How can I restart IDEA such that it reopens the files and the project tree?

Thank you.

EDIT: .idea/workspace.xml was broken - about 75 kb of nullbytes. Strange behaviour not to ask the user how to handle a broken config file.
I closed IntelliJ IDEA and deleted the file. Now files are reopened when a project is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to File | Settings, select Appearance & Behavior in the left panel, select System Settings in the left panel, and then select the "Reopen last project on startup" check box. If this option is selected, your last project should be opened after a restart, including the files that were open and the project tree.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: In response to the answer from @MartinPosider234: "It is checked. The project is reopened, but with colapsed project tree and without open editor tabs." -- That is strange. I am not aware of an option to select this type of behavior. So you close the project while one or more files are open and when you reopen it, those files are all closed? You can open the files manually?

Comment: Sorry for posting at the wrong position in the thread.

Yes, that is exactly what happens. (Well, I restart the progamm instead of closing and opening the project)

Comment: No problem! It looks like IntelliJ IDEA stores the files that are opened for a project in the `.idea/workspace.xml` file. There is an xml component named FileEditorManager that has file elements for all open files. You could try to "pin" files (right click on the tab and select "Pin Tab"). Also: do you have this problem for all your projects?

Comment: I tried "pin", because I thought that feature was to mark what will be reopened after a restart - but it did not work.

 I just noticed that IDEA also "forgets" the Run Configuration

Comment: I would create a small test project to make sure whether it happens for a single project or for all projects. You could also try the latest IntelliJ IDEA release to make sure it is not an issue of an older version (Version: 15.0.1, Build: 143.382, Released: November 12, 2015), see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: When the project is opened, an error message appers about a config file. Its just shown for about half a second, so I have not seen it yet.

Where is the log of IDEA?

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827517-Locating-IDE-log-files

Comment: Thank you Freek. Solution is in the first post.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it turned out simply deleting the workspace.xml file under my project's .idea folder resolved it. For it was most likely due to a corrupted setting after upgrading from Community -> Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the file `.idea/workspace.xml` may become corrupted. As a consequence, the project stops remembering the open files. Please check this file. If it contains anything else than proper XML, deleting the file and reopening the project helps.

Comment: This helped me!

Comment: Yeah, workspace.xml only showed 0 when I opened it,